# How to deny direct acceess to a file but allow access to use it in scripts in only my website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to deny direct access to a file, but allow access to use it in `<script>` tags only at my website.

Can someone please help me using PHP or .htaccess?

Comment: suppose you did achieve your goal, what would stop someone viewing the file in the browser source?

Comment: Using a `<script>` tag causes the browser to send a `HTTP GET` Request to your web server. That's basically the same as just opening the file directly in the browser from a protocol point of view. So, in other words: If you want to use JS file in a `<script>` tag it has to be accessible from the web - meaning everyone can look at it.

Comment: I expect you can do this by looking at the `HTTP_REFERER`. I'd try it with PHP first (where this variable can be inspected) but there may be a way to do it in .htaccess, which would be faster. Bear in mind the page referrer can be faked, but if other people try to use your JavaScript files on their own site, they would need their user's browsers to fake it too, which is most unlikely.

Comment: Just for the avoidance of doubt, the file in question _is_ JavaScript, right?

Comment: No, what you describe is impossible. Why do you want to do this? There  probably are other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The `src` attribute of a `<script>` tag is just a regular URL that can be accessed like any other URL. Nothing more, nothing less.

However, if you want to:

### Prevent unauthorised access

Move the JS file outside of the web server document root, so as to prevent direct access. Serve the JS file from a server-side script, only to authorised parties. Example in PHP:

file: publicScript.php

```
<?php
    if(access_granted()) { // use your usual authentication routine here
        header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
        readfile('/path/outsideOf/documentRoot/hiddenScript.js');
    } else {
        echo 'alert("access denied");';
    }
```

file: page.html

```
...
<head>
<script src="//publicScript.php"></script>
</head>
...
```

### Prevent unauthorised use of the JS

If the JS is supposed to issue HTTP requests (Ajax), keep in mind that it will also send session information (e.g. cookies) along. In fact, queries issued from JS are impossible to distinguish from a regular request (eg. click on a link), as far as the server is concerned. Such requests can be authenticated by your server just like any other request.

### Prevent reverse-engineering

Obfuscate your JS file. A quick search on your favourite search engine will return thousands of options.

If this still poses a security concern to you, then it is likely that your JS code is doing too much. Take critical features away from the JS and have your JS call a server-side API instead.